# Free electron transport theory derivation

Tags: solid-state-physics

I am going through the Introduction to solid state physics
Book by Charles Kittel.
In the section regrading Free electron transport theory, i am confused by a statement "In the absence of collisions the Fermi sphere (Fig. 10) moves in k space at a uniform rate by a constant applied electric field. " given in the book.

Since $d/dt = -eE$ this would imply a constant acceleration, and  increasing without limit

> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @noah, in the textbook it says '"In the absence of collisions the Fermi sphere (Fig. 10) moves in k space at a uniform rate by a constant applied electric field. " given in the book.' and since $dk/dt=−eE$ this would imply a constant acceleration, and  increasing without limt. This seems contradictory since a unifrom rate means no acceleration

Comment: Fermi sphere is in k-space - what you have here is a constant rate of change for *k* (that rate of change of momentum is acceleration in terms of coordinates is not relevant here... especially viewed from QM point of view.)

Comment: What is the question? If there is no resistance, as in this simple model, then yes, they accelerate "forever".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key part is

> the Fermi sphere moves **in $k$-space** at a uniform rate.

The $k$-space is where the momentum and thus also the energies live. If the Fermi sphere (and thus also the occupied $k$-states) moves uniformly, that means the momentum (and therefore also the energy) grows at a constant rate. In the case of no collisions, even without limit, as you say. So constant change in momentum space means accelerated motion in real space.